# org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem cannot be resolved

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

i add all jar files, but am getting this error
The type org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

please share the solutions..

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing Android application to read the doc file please include below jar files.

- poi-3.7.jar
- poi-scratchpad-3.2-FINAL.jar
  I got the same issue but I fixed with this solution.

Comment: I found no `org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem` in poi-scratchpad 5.2.3. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [POI jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/poi/poi-3.8-beta4-20110826.jar.zip). If you have already added it in your code, make sure that jar is in your classpath. If you are using windows then you can call "set" command in your command prompt and check the value of your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

add the poi.jar in the lib folder and run .

Answer (score 0):

try using `org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem` instead ... and add the `poi.5.2.3` jar in the lib folder and run